# Low speed for Atheros AR8151

Tags: networking, atheros

I hope someone can help! i've just cat6 cable through my house and hardwired my HTPC, I decided to do a quick speed test and was only getting ~91 Mb/s both devices have GB ports so i was expecting something higher. The HTPC runs Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64).

i did a:

```
 lspci
```

and got:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

and with

```
sudo ethtool enp2s0 | grep Speed
```

and got back: Speed: 100Mb/s

i found this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677122, but when i follow the instructions i get:

```
Makefile:173: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0. Stop.
```

which i guess is fair enough as the post is pretty old, what are my options get a faster speed? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you quite certain that you are using a known gigabit-capable cable, i.e. cat5e or cat6? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmmm nope! good call, the patch cables i'm using are probably quite old thinking about it. i shall check, if I am using a old cat5 cable would that be the reason why its only returning 100Mb/s when i run sudo ethtool enp2s0 | grep Speed ???

Comment: Absolutely! Been there and done that myself. *ethtool* will report the maximum that the ethernet card is able to negotiate with the router/switch. A small pipe means low speeds.

Comment: PS- If you have tp buy a better cable, I suggest that you get the very fastest available; that is the most future-proof. I prefer cat7 to cat6a if available and cat 6a over cat6 and so on. Please keep us posted.

Comment: Just swapped over the cable, the original cable didn't have any writing on it but it must be cat5 as I swapped it with another that says cat5e and now reporting 1000Mb/s. Lan speed test is showing 891Mb/s.... much better! school boy error, i should have checked! will look into getting a better cable in the future as eventually i will have 3 additional devices feeding off the HTPC. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I shall convert my comments to an answer that I hope you will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be quite certain that you are using a known gigabit-capable cable, i.e. cat 5e or cat 6 or better. If your computer has been connected for some time, it is entirely possible that it was connected with cat 5 which only supports 100 Mb/s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable

> Category 5 cable, commonly referred to as Cat 5, is a twisted pair
>   cable for computer networks. The cable standard provides performance
>   of up to 100 Mbps

If you have to buy a better cable, I suggest that you get the very fastest available; that is the most future-proof. I prefer cat7 to cat6a if available and cat 6a over cat6 and so on.

You might also temporarily swap in a known cat 5e or better cable to test the result.